# find a path that contains specific text

Tags: linux, unix

How do I find all paths that contain the string "tomcat" from a specific directory?
i.e. I want to find anything that contains tomcat1, tomcat2, tomcat3 etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
find . -iname tomcat\*
```

Replace the dot with your dir to search, or **cd** to the dir you want to search in.

If you only want to search for directory names, try

```
find . -type d -iname tomcat\*
```

Answer (score 4):

With Linux find (GNU findutils) 4.7 try `-wholename` test:

`find . -wholename */tomcat*`

or

`find . -type d -wholename */tomcat*`

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here can be a little confusing without context. The short answer is go look at the man page for `find`, but I can add some summary here. Essentially you want:

```
find <starting path> -iname "tomcat*"
```

You can change `-iname` to `-name` if you want it to be case sensitive. If you only want to search in the current directory and lower, you should use `.` as your starting directory. If you want to search the entire filesystem, use `/`. If you want to have any filename with tomcast, even if it's later in the file, use `"*tomcat*"`. You just need to figure out what's exactly right for your search.

Comment: I should probably also mention that this question is probably off topic for SO and is probably better for Super User.

Comment: +1 for compiling the gist of the other answers and giving a concise explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use find:

```
find / -name "tomcat*"
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `grep`:

```
grep -r "tomcat" dir
```